# how to print the context added template returned by the view

Tags: django

Just in curiosity to know , i want to get the printed html along with context  that is returned by my view .(I want get it printed on server side only).
 eg

```
def my_view(request):
    template='product/compare-in-box.html'
    context={"data": 'check',}
    # print(render(request , template ,context))   the thing i was trying to print but not working as i expect.
    return render(request , template,context)
```

product/compare-in-box.html  contains

```
<strong>{{data}}</strong>
```

I want the "print(render(request , template ,context))" to give me result as :
    `<stong> check </stong>`

how this can be achieved?

Comment: Just `print(context)`. You can print the content with `print(render(..).content)`

Comment: No what i want is take for  eg: compare-in-box.html  contains "<strong>{{data}}</strong>" and context={ 'data':'check' }  then print(render(request , ' compare-in-box.html ' ,context)) should give me <strong> check </strong>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **render_to_string** to do that like this `render_to_string('compare-in-box.html', context)`. It'll give whole HTML template in the form of string with context data placed inside template. [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)